# How to pass method pointer as argument in template class method

Tags: c++, templates, pointer-to-member

I am creating container template for different type. One of type will be `shared_ptr` to object. So for avoid duplicate code for operand `->` and `.` to calling object methods I m trying to pass pointer to method as function argument, but I got this error:

```
error: invalid use of non-static member function 'void A::show()'
 { doOperation(U::show); }
```

code:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class MepVector
{
private:
    typedef void(U::*Operation)();
public:
    MepVector() {}

    void doOperation(Operation operation)
    {
        for(const auto& t : mepVector_)
        {
            (t.*operation)();
        }
    }

    void add(T t)
    { mepVector_.push_back(t); }

    void show()
    { doOperation(U::show); }


private:
    std::vector<T> mepVector_;
};

class A
{
    public:
    A() {};
    void show()
    { cout<<"udalo sie!"<<endl; }
};

int main() {
    MepVector<A,A> myVector;

    myVector.add(A());

    myVector.show();

    return 0;
}
```

I don't want to make `A::show()` `static`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to:

```
void show()
{ doOperation(&U::show); }
```

However, you also have a second problem with:

```
    for(const auto& t : mepVector_)
    {
        (t.*operation)();
    }
```

Because `operation` is a pointer to a mutable class instance's function, this either have to be changed to:

```
    for(auto& t : mepVector_)
    {
        (t.*operation)();
    }
```

Or, `Operation` needs to be redefined accordingly:

```
typedef void(U::*Operation)() const;
```

Together with `A::show`'s also being a const method function:

```
void show() const
{  }
```

Answer (score -1):

First, you have to explicitly take address of `U::show` - `doOperation(&U::show);`. Compiler thinks you're trying to use the function as if it were `static`.

Second, you're trying to call `(t.*operation)();` with `const auto& t`, while `A::show` does not have `const` qualifier. Either make `A::show` along with the `Operation` `typedef` `const` or use `auto& t`.